Generating 2.5d or 3d Topography (Elevation) plots from 2d Z-stack height images
I have a set of Z-stack images i.e. 2d images of a sample that are grabbed at different Z slices with fixed Z step size. Is there a way to combine these N Z-stack images to form a 3d or 2.5d elevation/topography map of the sample?
Any reference to examples would be appreciated.
